# Screentime repeated entries for the same app

Tags: screen-time

I have two entries for Google Chrome on screen time, one of them has a ⚠️ infront of it.

What does this mean?

Comment: Is it Google Chrome for iPhone/iPad or Mac? What iOS/macOS version are you on? Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Guesswork - the app updated halfway through the period. The one with the triangle is the old version, no longer on the device.

Comment: Google Chrome for Mac, macOS Monterey.